# Django how to update model field from QueryDict

Tags: django, dictionary

I am a newbie in Django, maybe this will be a very simple question that I am not get the answer up until today.

Straight to my problems.

I have a submitted form and generated this:
***<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['bla bla bla'], 'id_number': ['1', '5', '17'], 'Status': ['Registered', 'Pending', 'Confirmed']}>***

I want to update my model field after the admin click on Update button something like this:

id# 1 --> Status change to Registered
id# 5 --> Status change to Pending
id# 17 --> Status change to Confirmed

Very appreciate for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if len(queryDict['id_number']) != len(queryDict['Status']):
        # check both lists have the same length and if they don't,  raise error

for i in range(len(queryDict['id_number'])):
    object = YourModel.objects.get(id=queryDict['id_number'][i])
    object.status = queryDict['Status'][i]
    object.save()
```

... you get the idea.
For optimization you could use the `@transaction.atomic` decorator.